# Adding listener to matchMedia.js polyfill issue

Tags: listener, polyfills, matchmedia

I am using https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/ along with the listener extension, however, I do not know how to write a listener for the match media query below. Any assistance would be much obliged.

#### JS:

```
if (matchMedia("(min-width: 52em)").matches) {
  $("details").attr("open", "open");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var handleMyMediaQuery = function(mql) {
        if (mql.matches) {
            // do match actions
        } else {
            // do unmatch actions
        }
    },
    myMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 52em)');

handleMyMediaQuery(myMediaQuery);
myMediaQuery.addListener(handleMyMediaQuery);
```

The first use of 'handleMyMediaQuery' checks immediately for a match to the media query and the second 'myMediaQuery.addListener(handleMyMediaQuery)' is triggered when the media query matches and then again when the media query does not match.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank-you David! I really appreciate the help, makes complete sense.